# How can I put multiple classes in a <li> element?

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am working with a navigation menu, and wondering how to put multiple classes in a li tag:

This is the `li` tag

```
 <li  class='pil' class='dropdown'>
```

And this is also what I want in the li tag:

```
class='{{ ($aktiv == 'dagvakt') ? 'active' : '' }}'
```

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
 <li  class='pil' class='dropdown'  class='{{ ($aktiv == 'dagvakt') ? 'active' : '' }}'>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add multiple classes to an element by putting them all in the same `class` attribute and separating them with a space. For example:

```
<li class='pil dropdown {{ ($aktiv == 'dagvakt') ? 'active' : '' }}'>
```

As far as I know, the spec only allows `class` to be declared once, so trying `<li class='ex' class='am' class='ple'>` won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Only one of each attribute can exist at one time, it should be a space-separated list of classes. Try this:

```
<li class="pil dropdown {{ ($aktiv == 'dagvakt') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Also careful using quotes `'` inside quotes, it's a good idea to use double quote `"` to assist syntax highlighting and to avoid any conflicts.