# Max-Height not working in CSS for Bootstrap site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [Freelancer theme](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/) and am trying to limit the height of my pictures for the portfolio by using max-height property. To do this, I gave the portfolio pictures a second class to add the property while not inadvertently changing something else like so:

```
<img src="img/portfolio/someimagename.jpg" class="img-responsive" class="img-portfolio" alt="">
```

I go to my css file to add the property like so:

```
.img-portfolio {
    max-height: 227px 
}
```

But my images aren't affected and are different heights still. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put multple classes in a <li>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062548/put-multple-classes-in-a-li)

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the second class in the wrong manner. This how you should add the second class:

```
<img src="img/portfolio/someimagename.jpg" class="img-portfolio img-responsive" alt="">
```

And then you can target both the classes, i.e. `.img-portfolio` and `.img-responsive`, separately using CSS.

The code which you've currently only assigns one class to the `<img>` which appears first inside the code, i.e. `img-responsive`, which is why your CSS for `.img-portfolio` isn't working.